# Vulkan advanced render design

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've finally managed to make it through the basic concepts of vulkan and have some knowledge of primary/secondary commandbuffers, renderpasses etc. Now I was wondering how one would design a more advanced render engine(not like the simples ones from the samples)?

Let me ask it more specifically:

If I would want to render a small village(a few houses) containing some villagers, which are animated using skeletal animation, how would the design approach look like? Would you create two Renderer classes, one for the villagers, one for the houses, each generating a secondary commandbuffer for each object? And if so, how would one make proper use of multithreading? <s>And if, lets say, every villager has its own pipeline(different textures, bonelayouts, etc), how would one manage those?</s>

**Edit:** I'm not searching for "the render engine", I just want to know how one could make effective use of multithreading then rendering a scene with different "types" of models(NPCs, houses, terrain).

Comment: "*every villager has its own pipeline(different textures, bonelayouts, etc)*" Why would using different textures or matrix sets necessitate having a different *pipeline*?

Comment: @NicolBolas What I initially meant with "multiple pipelines" was: Not evey model has the same vertex attributes(positions, normals, tangents, etc.), which means that one would need to generate at least a different layout for each model. But this has been resolved, since all data not included in each model is either unusable or has to be calculated with dummy values.

Comment: I think it is a very valid question! There were a lot of talks addressing this issue at GDC. First, don't re-implement a driver in Vulkan. It will not be better than the existing one. But with a careful design you can do things better. My favorite thing is separating copy/compute/raster. In a deferred render shading is only compute. Shadow maps are only raster.

Comment: @starmole: It may be a useful question, but it is not a *valid* one as far as SO is concerned. It's *way* too open-ended, even with the OP's edits. There are so many considerations that no one answer could possibly handle all of them. At best, this should go to Prog.SE, but I suspect it'd be too broad even for them.

Comment: @NicolBolas how about this: we keep this question on hold, and I ask some seperate, more detailed questions, since I already have an idea for a design now. After I got all the detailed information I need, I post an answer here explaining the concepts and ideas behind it including something like a diagramm

Comment: @Dynamitos: If you've got more specific questions in mind, go ahead and ask them. But the answers to them will not make *this question* any more appropriate for SO.

Comment: What happened to marking such questions as community wikis? I would also be interested in the answers people might post to this question.